# How to click on a WebElement using JavaScript using RobotFramework SeleniumLibrary in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, robotframework

I'm trying to click on a WebElement using JavaScript but I'm unable to create a JavaScript statement for that.

I'm able to click on a **Cancel** button using this statement

```
driver.execute_javascript("$(\"div[title='Cancel']\")[0].click()")
```

But on clicking another element which is more complicated, I'm trying this

```
expand_xpath = "//span[text()='Submit']//ancestor::table//a[text()='Expand']"
driver.execute_javascript("document.getElementByXpath('${expand_xpath}').click()")
```

*JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: document.getElementByXpath is not a function*

This **expand_xpath** is storing xpath of the WebElement which I need to click but I'm unable to frame the JS code for clicking this element.

Please find the RobotFramework **Execute Javascript** keyword expnation on this link
https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Execute%20Javascript

Second Try:

```
expand_xpath = "//span[text()='Submit']//ancestor::table//a[text()='Expand']"
driver.execute_javascript("document.evaluate('${expand_xpath}', document.body, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.click()")
```

Output:

```
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: We need to see the sample platform of yours.

Comment: @dpapadopoulos What do you mean by sample platform?

Comment: Against which platform does your code running? Do you have a link in order for us to practice?

Comment: @dpapadopoulos I'm using RobotFramework with Python. It's not possible for you to practice.

Comment: RobotFramework has nothing to do with that. In any case, it would be much easier for possible helpers of you to have the sample of your code and the platform that your scripts are running on.

Comment: @dpapadopoulos You can consider I'm using Selenium based on Python with RobotFramework Library

Comment: Can you upload the link from the site you are running your automation project? I am not saying robot framework or selenium links. I am saying the platform you are testing. You want to click on a button. This button belongs to which platform? That's the platform I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking on element using below javaScript :

```
 element= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Submit']//ancestor::table//a[text()='Expand']")
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

OR use below:

```
expand_xpath = "//span[text()='Submit']//ancestor::table//a[text()='Expand']"
driver.execute_javascript("document.getElementByXPath('${expand_xpath}').click()")
```

Note: "P" is in uppercase in *XPath*.

Comment: I have tried this out and it will say that argument expected should be of type string. This is not the same as we do in selenium using JAVA.

Comment: `expand_element = driver.get_webelement("//span[text()='Submit']//ancestor::table//a[text()='Expand']")
driver.execute_javascript("arguments[0].click()", expand_element)`

**Output:**
_TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, WebElement found_

Comment: i have updated my answer and converted javascriot statement as String value. Please try the code.

Comment: No, I have already provided you the output by using that method

Comment: Please Note I have updated my answer. There is a semicolon with the statement. Use :   `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Comment: _TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, WebElement found_
I guess the execute_javascript expects only one argument

Comment: Okay, in your original post i see you are using ‘getElementByXpath’. Instead, please use ‘ getElementByXPath’. 
“P” is also in uppercase.

Comment: _JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: document.getElementByXPath is not a function_

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using RobotFramework, this one is quite easy:

```
${locator}    //button[@id='abc']
Execute JavaScript    document.evaluate("${locator}", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()
```

Note that the inputted xpath should not contain double quote (") character, only single quote (') to prevent JS parsing error

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method to deal with the click.

**Arguments:**
ele_xpath : XPATH of the element to be clicked.

```
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary  

def click_element_with_javascript(ele_xpath):
            try:
                js_exp = "document.evaluate(\"##xpath##\", document.body, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.click()".replace('##xpath##', ele_xpath)
                driver.execute_javascript(js_exp)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Element click through javascript resulted in Exception: {}".format(e))
```